# A http proxy same as Fiddler AutoResponder

Tags: python, node.js, http, proxy, fiddler

Hey I'm trying to create something like fiddler autoresponder.

I want replace specific url content to other example:

I researched everything but can't found I tried create proxy server, nodejs script, python script. Nothing.

`https://randomdomain.com content replace with https://cliqqi.ml`

ps I'm doing this because I want intercept electron app getting main game file from site and then just intercept they game file site to my site.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to do this programmatically in Node.js, I've written a library you can use to do exactly that, called [Mockttp](https://github.com/httptoolkit/mockttp).

You can use Mockttp to create a HTTPS-intercepting & rewriting proxy, which will allow you to send mock responses directly, redirect traffic from one address to another, rewrite anything including the headers & body of existing traffic, or just log everything that's sent & received. There's a full guide here: https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/javascript-mitm-proxy-mockttp/

Comment: It gives me back a error 

```describe("Mockttp", () => {
^

ReferenceError: describe is not defined``` ps I'm doing this because I want intercept electron app getting main game file from site and then just intercept they game file site to my site.

Comment: 'describe' is part of Mocha and other test frameworks, it's just used in the README as an example for that use case. I would suggest you work through the examples in the full guide to start with since they're much more detailed.

Comment: Hmm I really can't do that what I wanted its possible to do what I want? "intercept electron app getting main game file from site and then just intercept they game file site to my site. Literlly just redirect site from site." I have problems with certificates